# Migrate to Paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

I want to migrate an older PagedListAdapter to PagingDataAdapter, but cant find analogue of onCurrentListChanged method from PagedListAdapter.

How can I implement similar behavior on PagingDataAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Paging 3 specialist, but I took a look and saw that Paging 3 uses Kotlin Coroutines and works with Flows and I think you can observe the
[onPagesUpdatedFlow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagingDataAdapter#onPagesUpdatedFlow()) atribute from your `PagingDataAdapter`

Since this will give you a Flow, you will have to retrieve the itens by hand using `snapshot().items`. You can save the elements on a field called `previousList` and when they change, you'll have both `currentList` and `previousList`.

Maybe there's a better way to do it, but if it works for you, great :)

Comment: Need access to previous list and current list like in onCurrentListChanged, so I don't think it's the right solution

Comment: @LandMark1919 I changed the answer. See if it helps :)

Comment: Maybe you also know an analogue of the PagedList.loadaround method?)

Comment: @LandMark1919 Right now I unfortunately do not :(